# How to deploy revel framework(Go lang) using nginx

Tags: go, revel

I like to ask, how can i deploy my revel framework app using nginx in different linten port, for example port 8089. Thank you

Comment: Can somebody helm me. thanx

Comment: There is a deleted answer to your question which apparently answers the question. You replied: `i already did that. but the go lang code doesn't read. html code was only read`. Can you please fix your question so it demonstrates your actual problem?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question, I assume you are trying to reverse proxy from nginx to your revel framework application. Essentially using proxy pass forwards HTTP request headers from one port/application to another. This allows you to use your web application directly.

If this is the case, you'll need to do the following:

- Start the app on some port (say 8089)
- Configure Nginx to handle reverse proxy web connections from port 80 / 443 to that port.
- Navigate to the URL specified by the Nginx proxy pass configuration.

[This link from Nginx should be helpful in setting up the proxy pass.](http://nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/)

If this is not what you are trying to achieve, let me know and I'll try to help out some more!